# Better use of syntax in if else statement to choose season based on a variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax

I'm using an else if statement to tell me the current season (In the Southern Hemisphere)

```js
const MONTH = 'March'

if (MONTH == 'December'|| MONTH == 'January'|| MONTH == 'February'){
   console.log('Summer')
}
else if (MONTH == 'March'|| MONTH == 'April'|| MONTH == 'May'){
  console.log('Autumn')
}
else if (MONTH == 'June'|| MONTH == 'July'|| MONTH == 'August'){
  console.log('Winter')
}
else console.log('Spring')
```

While this works, the repeated use of MONTH is not a great way to go about it.

What would be a better way to write this code, still using an if else statement?

Comment: I don't see anything specifically wrong with this, although I'm a fan of arrays, so I'd probably do something like `if("December","January","February].includes(MONTH)){...}`

Comment: Use a switch statement


`switch (month) {
  case 'December':
  case 'January':
  case 'February':

   console.log('a'); break; case '': ....
}` 

or `if (['December','January','February'].includes(month)){} else if....`

Comment: Thanks @mykaf, I feel like it's a bit of an easier way to read the code writing it like that.